# MySQL query with 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have this tables in my DB:

> Id_People | Name_People 
>       
>         1                  Milton
>               2                  Aragon
>           3                  Legolas

Well I create a Table with Dad and Son like this:

> Id_Dad   |    Id_Son
>       
>         1                  2
>               2                  3

How can I write a query to obtain records with ids common to both Son and Dad columns (example: id 2, in the above table)?

Comment: what do you mean children like 2?  having 2 children? find the dad who has a son with an ID 2?   Find records that are both father and son?

Comment: yes, Find records that are both father and son

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as efficient; but it gives greater flexibility on the data to output.  We use a self join and table alias to join to the Dad/Son table (I called it relationship)  using an INNER join will guarantee only records that are both father and son are returned.

```
Select R.*, R2.*
FROM Relationship R
INNER JOIN Relationship R2
 on R.ID_Son = R.ID_Dad
```

Depending on needed field output this is the most efficient way; but it limits what data is available to output.  This approach uses a correlated subquery to obtain all records where the son is also a father.

```
SELECT R.* 
FROM Relationship R
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from RelationShip R2 where R.ID_Son = R2.ID_DAD)
```

In both cases more than 1 record per father could be returned, due to multiple children.  But it guarantees that the record is both father and "Son"

Comment: well if I want obtain the Name only?

Comment: Use R.Name_People instead of R.*